# FragmentActivity with TabHost. How would you do this?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a 5 tabs TabHost on my FragmentActivity, where on the 4th I have a AsyncTask which makes a ProgressDialog (this PD has false on setCanceledOnTouchOutside), and the 5th doesn't make it.

My problem is: when I click on the 4th tab and suddenly on the 5th, the 5th gets opened with the ProgressDialog on 4th, and that gets me in trouble if I want to cancel the AsyncTask or whatever thing I do (toast, results, etcetera).

I know I could try/catch everything, but it's not a good practice.

**I've tried:**

- Set TabHost enabled = false at the beginning of `onTabChanged` and enabled = true at the end of the same `onTabChanged` with no success.
- Set TabHost enabled = false at the beginning of `onTabChanged` and enabled = true at `onResume` of the Fragment, so I could load the PD on `onCreateView` with enabled = false and then enabled = true after, so `onResume`. With no success (it appears visibility after onResume).

What should I do?
I was thinking about making my own widgets, progressdialog and doing it with try/catch.

Thanks in advance.

---

**ADDING**

I'm using this structure for Tabs... it uses a BaseFragment where if I press back, it removes one fragment from a hashMap.

https://github.com/thankimanish/TabUsingFragment/tree/master/src/com/android/hdik/main

Answer (score 0):

Start the `Asynctask` in `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` method of Fragment, this way you will start the `Asynctask` only when the `Fragment` is visible to user, now simply hide it in `onPause()` of fragment, or as soon as you fragment visibility.

Comment: Hi twntee, thanks for your answer... could you give me some documentation about this method?

Comment: My pardon, I wrongly mentioned the method name, please see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)

Comment: Hi again twntee. In my case setUserVisibleHint is never called. In fact, I think I have to have the control of "isVisible" and I don't want that. I create my views on onCreateView and then I launch the AsyncTask, when the ProgressDialog is made.